# How to disable WPA auth/encryption from an AP configuration

Tags: pi-3, access-point

I have already configured a Raspberry Pi 3 as an Access Point by performing a series of steps given at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

I would like to configure it as an "open" network. That is, remove the authentication which is now required while connecting to the network.

Comment: I tweaked your title to reflect the fact that "removing authentication" means you can't use WPA encryption, ie., no authentication is required, but there will be no encryption either.  Have a look at `man 5 hostapd.conf`, and/or search online about configuring `hostapd` that way; pretty sure it just requires you remove all the `wpa_` options.

Comment: You will find a tested setup, but using **wpa_supplicant** instead of **hostapd** to make the access point: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866)

Answer (score 2):

From the  /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf file you should remove these lines:

```
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=***************
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And should be done with that.

Comment: What `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` do you mean where I can remove lines?

Comment: @AlessandroRodriguez This is exactly what I did on a hit-and-trial basis, and that worked. I would appreciate if you could explain the workings of each of these configurations.

Comment: @Ingo `hostapd.conf` is the file where you configure the network settings like `interface` where your device listens to, `ssid` of the network, network password (`wpa_passphrase`), etc. A sample `hostapd.conf` file is given at the link in the original question.